# Consume Microsoft Graph API from backend service (node.js)

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I want to send emails using Microsoft Graphs API from a backend service developed in node.js, that has no interactions with the user.

If I understand it correctly from [this paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/auth-v2-service#administrator-consent-experience), if I use the [Get access without user](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/auth-v2-service) procedure, the administrator will have to give me some rights and then I will have those rights on every user account in the organization. This is not my goal, I only want to have those rights for one specific account, for which I have the login and password.

Is there a way to log in with an office365 account without user interaction?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to have the user authenticate in order to obtain the initial access token and refresh token (to refresh your permission to access the account).

Comment: I also has the same requirement but still searching for the solution

Comment: There is no alternative to authenticated consent, and there shouldn't be. Allowing an app to interact with a User's data without that User authenticating and providing consent would violate just about every fundamental security guideline.